# Deploying war file on linux tomcat with spring

Tags: linux, windows, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

I've got .war file that works fine in windows tomcat 7.0.40. But on Linux I get following:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryUtils

and my spring app doesn't work. What can be wrong? jar file spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar is there in webapps. What can be wrong?

Thanx.

Comment: Is spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar located in WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: yes, it is there and it is un-.war-ed.

Comment: Do you have all jar files that spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar depends on?

Comment: yes, war is valid on Windows

Comment: I'm guessing file permissions. Post the directory/file structure of your deployment / Tomcat installation.

Comment: it might be permission as commented above or jdk version... check if the windows and linux have the same sdk version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem before. I remove the tomcat completely and reinstalled it, then it worked. try it.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the problem by reinstalling tomcat on Debian with --purge option. The reason remains secret.